# Return to mainview from webView deployed using storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, webview

I created a new project "Single View Application" and designed the mainView with Storyboard. My main view contains a UIButton that opens the camera, the camera scans barcode and automatically goes to a website. Now I created a webView programmatically so that website can open and also created a UIButton inside the webView. Now I want that UIButton to act as home botton and return to mainview. I am unable to do that, please help.

ViewController.m code: http://cl.ly/FKj8

My storyboard looks like:
[image]

Comment: How you get back from the web view depends on how you got to it. Did you insert it into the view hierarchy of the single view controller, or segue to another view controller? If the latter, is it presented as a modal view controller or pushed onto a navigation controller?

Comment: I implemented it inside a single view controller

Answer (score 1):

You really should look into the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) -- by switching around the contents of a single view controller, you're making a lot of extra work for yourself with little benefit. By using multiple view controllers when you want to have different "screens" in your app, you can take advantage of storyboarding for easier development, and you automatically get better memory management (read: less potential for crashes), too.

However, to more directly answer your question... if you're putting the WebView into the view hierarchy with `[self.view addSubview:webView]`, you can remove it with `[webView removeFromSuperview]`. (This means you'll have to keep a reference to the WebView around so you can refer to it when you want to dismiss it.)

---

I also noticed in the code you posted to cl.ly an unrelated method `-deviceModel` which uses `uname()` to get device information. This is a bad idea, for two reasons:

- `uname()` isn't guaranteed to do something useful on an iOS device (even if it currently does). Use the `UIDevice` class instead if you need this kind of info, or...
- Generally, you **don't** want to test for the device name to enable functionality in your app; instead, you should test for the capabilities you need. (For example, if you look for a device name starting with "iPhone 4" to test for a Retina display, you'll miss the 4th-generation iPod touch, and the iPhone-5-or-whatever-they-call-what's-next. Instead, use the `UIScreen` class.)

Comment: Implementing [webView removeFromSuperview] shows error as it has no reference in that button pressed method. How will I implement that

Comment: Keep a reference to it when you create it -- say, in an ivar.

Comment: How will I do that? Please help, as I am a complete newbie here.

Comment: Declare an instance variable. When you create the UIWebView, assign it to that instead of a local variable. If you're not sure what these things mean, you should look into the [ObjC language docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) or search Google... much has already been written on how to get started with the language.

Comment: Sir, please look at this and help
I declared this on header 
`@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView; `
and this on implementation file
`@synthesize webView;`
and 
`[self.webView removeFromSuperview];` inside the buttonPressed method and now it is working as I wanted, but has only one issue the button (Home) I created to return from webView to mainView, is also visible after that button is used. Any way to release or hide it.

Comment: You can remove the button in the same way you remove the web view, or simply set its `hidden` property.